# "405 Method Not Allowed" in Python webapp2

Tags: python, webapp2

```
import webapp2

form="""
     <form method="post">
          <input type="" name="day">
          <input type="" name="month">
          <input type="" name="year">
          <input type="submit" name="">
     </form>
     """
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self):
    self.response.out.write(form)

def post(self):
    self.response.out.write("thank")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),], debug=True)
```

this code responds with

> 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> The method POST is not allowed for this resource.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and fix the indentation of the posted code, so that we can see what is part of the `class` and what isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something with your configuration. I tested your code almost identical to what you posted and it responds correctly (with google appengine).

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    form = """
         <form method="post">
              <input type="" name="day">
              <input type="" name="month">
              <input type="" name="year">
              <input type="submit" name="">
         </form>
         """
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(self.form)

    def post(self):
        self.response.out.write("thank")


app = microwsgi.MicroWSGIApplication([
                                      ('/MainPage', MainPage)...
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. The editor you are using has a wrong configuration for "indentation", which is crucial for python's interpreter to interpret the code correctly.

Try re-write this program with Python IDE.